# Running Spring Boot Application on a different machine

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm creating a Spring Boot CRUD Application, and I want it to run on another computer.
I use Spring Boot + JPA-Hibernate + MySQL.

I understand MySQL is just file. And the DataSource means the server, in my case localhost 3306, where the db is.. Right?

I can access MySQL db as the data source is running on my machine. But when i take the application to a different computer which is not on a network, I have to create the data source, which is the localhost and put my mysql files there. Right?

My question is, whether there's a way which doesn't involve the user to start database server every single time they need the CRUD app to work. I'm trying to create a standalone app btw.

Is there a way to start the server from within our spring boot app with sql files, as if we do with SQLite, which is a serverless db?

Comment: Your question is not clear, so you will need to clarify what your goal is and how your application is structured (more details). Are you asking whether or not your application can connect to the existing database, or are you asking how to automatically deploy and create a new database on whichever database server you happen to be using just by starting your Spring Boot?

Comment: I'm asking about initializing a data source, which is MySQL here.. If I copy the sql files I have to a new PC and run the application Jar, would it work?

Comment: A DataSource is a Java object allowing to get connections to a database. The database can be on the same machine, or somewhere else on the network. You define its location by specifying its URL when configuring the DataSource. MySQL is a database. It's not a DataSource. SQL files are just files. They're neither a DataSource, nor a database. They just contain SQL instructions that can be sent to a database for execution. Now, what are you asking? Please answer Pytry's question, with the corrrect terminology.

Comment: I shall edit the question

Comment: Question updated

Comment: *I understand MySQL is just file*: no. It's a database server, that needs to be installed on some machine, and accepts connections from that machines or other machines. *the DataSource means the server,*: no. A DataSource is a Java object allowing to get connections to a database, like MySQL. You apparently haven't read my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks.  Now it makes perfect sense..

Comment: But what's the best solution for my question? Please go through the comments under Augusto Neto answer

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot gives you defaults on all things, the default in database is H2, so when you want to change this and use any other database you must define the connection attributes in the application.properties file.

In the sources folder, you create a resource file src/main/resources/application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
```

- spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto can be none, update, create, create-drop, refer to the Hibernate documentation for details.
- none This is the default for MySQL, no change to the database structure.
  update Hibernate changes the database according to the given Entity structures.
- create Creates the database every time, but don’t drop it when close.
- create-drop Creates the database then drops it when the SessionFactory closes.

Starts begin with create because we don’t have the database structure yet. After the first run, we could switch it to update or none according to program requirements. Use update when you want to make some change to the database structure.

The default for H2 and other embedded databases is create-drop, but for others like MySQL is none

It is good security practice that after your database is in production state, you make this none and revoke all privileges from the MySQL user connected to the Spring application, then give him only SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE.

Make the application executable.

Although it is possible to package this service as a traditional WAR file for deployment to an external application server, the simpler approach demonstrated below creates a standalone application. You package everything in a single, executable JAR file, driven by a good old Java main() method. Along the way, you use Spring’s support for embedding the Tomcat servlet container as the HTTP runtime, instead of deploying to an external instance.

src/main/java/hello/Application.java

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have a doubt though. How would you run this executable on another machine? Like a pc. There won't be a database server right?

Comment: Using spring boot you have the possibility to create a standalone app with embedded database. At the end you build an executable jar file that contains all the necessary dependencies, classes, and resources, and run that. This makes it easy to ship, version, and deploy the service as an application throughout the development lifecycle, across different environments, and so forth.

Comment: Is it simply making executable with the h2 database that gets generated? Your answer sounds promising